# NGINX redirect rewrite "/([0-9]+)" /showthread.php?t=$1 break;

Tags: nginx

I'd like to redirect this kind of url:

exemple.com/index.php?threads/hello-how-are-you.326517/

to

exemple.com/showthread.php?t=326517

I tried:

```
 location ~ /[0-9]+ {
  rewrite "/([0-9]+)" /showthread.php?t=$1 break;
```

}

but it does'nt work fine.
Could you help me please?
H

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to match something that doesn't exist in the URI, your regex exists in $args and $query_string, I'm not sure if this will work but you can try

```
if ($args ~ "threads/.*\.([0-9]+)$") {
  try_files /showthread.php?t=$1 =404;
}
```